# How do i find and edit specific elements atributtes in wordpress template php files?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new to Wordpress and I need to continue a web page some other developer started. The last developer left the template default placeholders and texts and most of them need to be changed. For example: I need to change the newsletter pop-up input placeholder which html code, taken from chrome inspection tool, is:

```
<input placeholder="Your E-Mail" type="text" name="widget_subscribe" class="widget_subscribe large">
```

With this information, first I tried changing it in the app.css, only to realize that placeholders aren't modifiables in css. Then I tried going to the theme editor and looking for specific keywords in each php file, like "widget_subscribe" and "input", but got frustrated midway. I couldn't find any file name that belonged to the newsletter subscription pop-up. Is there some way to view which file has the code I'm looking for?

If it helps i'm using the template "The Issue" by fuelthemes and the webpage im working on is http://cmagwordpress.com.ar/

I would really appreciate any help you could give me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in the theme file. `The Issue` theme, file `inc/templates/post-detail-bits/subscribe.php`.

Although it is not recommended, you are able to change the text of the popup in `Appearance` -> `Theme Editor` and find `subscribe.php`

[image]

If this helps you, please mark this as the answer!